# Estimating incidence from posterior distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian

I'm new to R and using "rethinking" package for Bayesian statistics. I am trying to estimate Incidence from posterior distribution from the data I have (i.e. prevalence and duration of illness). I have the prevalence data (people who has fever in the past 2 weeks) and duration of fever is assumed to be 7 days. I tried to calculate Incidence per person-year from the posterior.

Here is my R codes

```
library(rethinking)

# Prevalence of fever (in the past two weeks)

fev <- c(132)  # people with fever 
no.fev <- c(675)   # people with no fever 

fever.p1 <- quap(
  alist(
    fever ~ dbinom( fever+no.fever ,p) ,  # binomial likelihood
    p ~ dbeta(10, 90)     # beta prior, alpha = 10, beta = 90
  ), data=list(fever=132,no.fever=675) )

precis(fever.p1)

sample_fev <- extract.samples(fever.p1, 1e5)

# Duration of fever

# Define prior
flist <- alist(
  duration ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
  mu ~ dnorm(14, 6),  # mean = 14 days, sd = 6 days
  sigma ~ dunif(0, 7) # uniform distribution between 0 and 7
)
 # Simulation of data 

duration <- rnorm(1e3, 7, 3). # mu= 7 days and sigma = 3 days

d <-as.data.frame(duration)

fev.d <- quap(flist,data = d)

precis(fev.d)

sample_fev_d <- extract.samples(fev.d, 1e5)

# Incidence of fever 

fever.i = sample_fev / sample_fev_d
```

I did not get the incidence from the posterior from the codes below? I don't know which codes are wrong.